# Order by ENUM fields for association tables

Tags: postgresql, sorting, enums, sequelize.js, sql-order-by

I have tried two solutions:

- casting `ORDER BY CAST(type AS CHAR)`
- case inside sequelize literal `sequelize.literal(case when type=typeone then '0' when type=typetwo then '1' else '2' end')`

both works if the field is in the table I directly query but can't figure out how to do this for association tables.

For example:

```js
Seller.findById({
 where: {
    id: 'seller-id',
  },
  include: {
    model: Product,
    include: Category
  },
  order: [
    // sort on a string field works
    [Product, Category, 'name', 'DESC']
    // sort by enum doesn't
    [Product, Category, CAST(type AS CHAR), 'DESC']
  ]
});
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help with your issues, but there are certain expectations on you. Please spend a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. 
 Then update your question to include sample data, table definition (ddl scripts), the expected results of that data, all as text - **no images**; even better create a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/).  Further clearly describe what you are attempting and where you are having issues.